# How to put data in a table without overflow

Tags: html, css

When the text in a table cell is larger than the width, it overflows the cell. [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klgor.png)

i remove `white-space: nowrap;` [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cX9P.png)

I need when text in a cell larger than the width, put on cell txt Break.

/***************************************************************************/

This is my table code:

```
<div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header">
    <div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-title">
        <label>title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-time">
        <label>date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-type">
        <label>type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-operation">
        <label>operation</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element">
    <div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-title">
        <label>txttitle</label>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-time">
        <label>date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-type">
        <label>type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-operation">
        <label>operation</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000000;
    border-top:2px solid #000000;
    border-right:2px solid #000000;
    border-left:2px solid #000000;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-title {
    width: 376px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    height: 46px;
    float: right;
    text-align:center;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-title label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-time {
    width: 140px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    height: 46px;
    float: right;
    text-align:center;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-time label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-type {
    width: 140px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    height: 46px;
    float: right;
    text-align:center;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-type label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-operation {
    width: 178px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    height: 46px;
    text-align:center;
    float: right;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header-operation label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element{
    margin-right:2px;
}

/************************************************/

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-title {
    width: 376px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    float: right;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000000;
    word-break:break-all;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-title label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-time {
    width: 140px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    float: right;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000000;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-time label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-type {
    width: 140px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    float: right;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000000;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-type label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-operation {
    width: 178px;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    float: right;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000000;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element-operation label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element{
    margin-right:2px;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even demonstrate the problem. The is nothing that overflows its parent element. Please try to always give a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
    .main-container-list-news-tabel-container-header>div,.main-container-list-news-tabel-container-element>div{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just forgot something, now try it. It work for me.

Comment: I think you should remove this line from your css     "white-space: nowrap;"

Comment: i remove this . i put the pic